# React, show array element according to timestamp

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

The feature I would like to implement is that the React component shows the task that would be taking place according to the timestamps of the data that are in the data array.

Each of the elements of the array has two timestamps, the timestamp of when the task is started and when the task is finished.

However, unfortunately I don't know how I could make the component dynamically show the task that will be executed.

That is, if there is a task to be executed, it would show the task that is being started, otherwise, it doesn't show the task and waits until the next task in the array starts so that it can show it.

I hope I'm not being confused

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Read book"
    start: "2021-12-30T14:41:39+0000",
    end: "2021-12-30T15:41:39+0000"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Clean desk"
    start: "2021-12-30T17:01:39+0000",
    end: "2021-12-30T17:24:39+0000"
  }
]

const App = () => {
  const [currentTask, setCurrentTask] = useState(undefined)
  
  useEffect(() => {
    setCurrentTask(getCurrentTask())
  }, [currentTask])

  const getCurrentTask = () => {
    return data ? data.find((task) => new Date(data.start).getTime() <= Date.now()) : undefined
  }

  return (
    <>
     {currentTask ? <div>{currentTask.title}</div> : <div>No current task</div>}
    </>
  )
}
```

How could I implement this?

Comment: you want to live check of tasks date to update component automatically?

Comment: Yes! sorry for not being able to express myself properly

Comment: does your data comes from server in live or it comes once the page load and after that you have to decide what task would show?

Comment: it comes from the api via an http request

Comment: You can do this by setInterval or useInterval to periodically check the task every x seconds or minutes and update the state, if you think this is solve your problem I would post it as answer

Comment: Yes please! It would be a possible solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240572/discussion-between-hdm91-and-learnbydoing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using `setInterval` or [useInterval](https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-interval) to periodically check the data and update the state based on start datetime, I put the useInterval code from the library here to see how to use setInterval correctly in react:

useInterval:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from "react";

export function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef(callback);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!delay && delay !== 0) {
      return;
    }

    const id = setInterval(() => savedCallback.current(), delay);

    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, [delay]);
}
```

App Component:

```
import React, {useState} from "react";
import useInterval from "./useInterval";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Read book",
    start: "2021-12-30T19:33:20",
    end: "2021-12-30T19:20:20",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Clean desk",
    start: "2021-12-30T19:31:39",
    end: "2021-12-30T19:25:39",
  },
];

const App = () => {
  const [currentTask, setCurrentTask] = useState(undefined);
  useInterval(
    () => {
      const currentTask = getCurrentTask();
      setCurrentTask(currentTask);
    },
    // Delay in milliseconds or null to stop it
    60000
  );

  const getCurrentTask = () => {
    return data
      ? data.find((task) => {
          const startTime = new Date(task.start).getTime();
          const endTime = new Date(task.end).getTime();
          const now = Date.now();

          return startTime <= now && endTime >= now;
        })
      : undefined;
  };

  return (
    <>
      {currentTask ? (
        <div>{currentTask.title}</div>
      ) : (
        <div>No current task</div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```